Operator norm of a positive semidefinite matrix valued function
Let $\Omega$ is a measure space and $A:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n \times n},\,x \mapsto A(x)$ is a measurable function such that $A(x)$ is an $n \times n$ positive semidefinite matrix.
$A = A(\cdot)$ acts on the space of $\mathbb{C}^n$- valued functions $\mathbf{f}(x) = (f_i(x))_{i=1}^n$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n \int|f_i(x)|^2\,dx< \infty$, with norm $\|\mathbf{f}\| = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \int |f_i(x)|^2\,dx\right)^{1/2}$.
Thus,
$$\|A\|_{op} = \sup_{\mathbf{f} \neq 0} \frac{\|A\mathbf{f}\|}{\|\mathbf{f}\|}$$
A paper that I am reading states that it is well known that
$$\|A\|_{op} = \text{ess sup}_{x \in \Omega} \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \lambda_i(A)(x)$$
where $\lambda_1(A)(x),\dots,\lambda_n(A)(x)$ are the eigenvalues of $A(x)$.
I know that if $A$ was not a function but a constant matrix, then its operator norm would be the maximum of its eigenvalues. How do I prove this result for matrix valued functions?

The supremum over $x \in \Omega$ should be changed to essential supremum. Otherwise $A$ can be changed on a null set without altering its operator norm but changing the supremum greatly.

@DavidGao You are right, I have edited the question.

(I’m assuming the measure space is actually semifinite, i.e., for any $E \subset \Omega$ with $\mu(E) = \infty$, there exists $F \subset E$ s.t. $0 < \mu(F) < \infty$. The result is false otherwise. But this is a quite usual restriction - any $\sigma$-finite measure space is semifinite, for example.)
Since you already know the constant case, what we need to prove here is actually,
$$\|A\|_{op} = \text{ess sup}_{x \in \Omega} \|A(x)\|_{op}$$
Now, $\|A\|_{op} \leq \text{ess sup}_{x \in \Omega} \|A(x)\|_{op}$ just follows from,
$$\begin{split}
\|A\mathbf{f}\|^2 &= \int_\Omega \|A(x)\mathbf{f}(x)\|_2^2 \, dx\\
&\leq \text{ess sup}_{x \in \Omega} \|A(x)\|_{op}^2 \int_\Omega \|\mathbf{f}(x)\|_2^2 \, dx\\
&= \text{ess sup}_{x \in \Omega} \|A(x)\|_{op}^2 \|\mathbf{f}\|^2
\end{split}$$
For the converse, let $0 < \epsilon < 1$. By the definition of essential supremum, there exists $\Omega’ \subset \Omega$ of positive measure s.t. $\|A(y)\|^2_{op} \geq \text{ess sup}_{x \in \Omega} \|A(x)\|^2_{op} - \epsilon$ for all $y \in \Omega’$. By semifiniteness, we may assume $\mu(\Omega’) < \infty$. Now, fix a countable dense sequence $\{h_k\}_k$ in the unit sphere of $\mathbb{C}^n$. For each $k$, let,
$$\Omega_k = \{x \in \Omega’: \|A(x)h_k\|_2 \geq (1 - \epsilon)\|A(x)\|_{op}\}$$
Since $\{h_k\}_k$ is dense in the unit sphere, $\bigcup_k \Omega_k = \Omega’$. Thus, there exists some $k$ s.t. $\mu(\Omega_k) > 0$. Note that we also have $\mu(\Omega_k) \leq \mu(\Omega’) < \infty$. Let $\mathbf{f} = \chi_{\Omega_k}h_k$ (i.e., $\mathbf{f}$ evaluates to $h_k$ on $\Omega_k$ and $0$ otherwise). Then, $\|\mathbf{f}\|^2 = \mu(\Omega_k)$, and,
$$\begin{split}
\|A\mathbf{f}\|^2 &= \int_{\Omega_k} \|A(x)h_k\|_2^2 \, dx\\
&\geq (1 - \epsilon)^2 \int_{\Omega_k} \|A(x)\|_{op}^2 \, dx\\
&\geq (1 - \epsilon)^2(\text{ess sup}_{x \in \Omega} \|A(x)\|^2_{op} - \epsilon)\mu(\Omega_k)
\end{split}$$
So, $\|A\|^2_{op} \geq (1 - \epsilon)^2(\text{ess sup}_{x \in \Omega} \|A(x)\|^2_{op} - \epsilon)$. As this holds for all $0 < \epsilon < 1$, letting $\epsilon \to 0$ shows $\|A\|_{op} \geq \text{ess sup}_{x \in \Omega} \|A(x)\|_{op}$.
